# CNN model is giving wrong predictions

Tags: python, keras, digit

I am currently working on handwritten digit recognition of regional languages. Currently, I am focusing on Oriya. I test the MNIST dataset through the CNN model and I am trying to apply the model on my Oriya dataset. Model is performing poorly. It is giving the wrong predictions. I have a dataset of 4971 samples.
How to improve the accuracy?
Here's my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten  
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,adam
from keras.utils import np_utils

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import os
import theano
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
# SKLEARN
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split



# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)



# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# number of channels
img_channels = 1


path2 = '/home/saumya/Desktop/Oriya/p'    #path of folder of images


imlist = os.listdir(path2)


im1 = array(Image.open('/home/saumya/Desktop/Oriya/p' + '/'+ imlist[0]))    # open one image to get size
m,n = im1.shape[0:2] # get the size of the images
imnbr = len(imlist) # get the number of images


# create matrix to store all flattened images
immatrix = array([array(Image.open('/home/saumya/Desktop/Oriya/p' + '/'+  im2)).flatten()
           for im2 in imlist],'f')

label=np.ones((num_samples,),dtype = int)
label[1:503]=0
label[503:1000]=1
label[1000:1497]=2
label[1497:1995]=3
label[1995:2493]=4
label[2493:2983]=5
label[2983:3483]=6
label[3483:3981]=7
label[3981:4479]=8
label[4479:4972]=9

print(label[1000])
data,Label = shuffle(immatrix,label, random_state=2)
train_data = [data,Label]

img=immatrix[2496].reshape(img_rows,img_cols)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()



(X, y) = (train_data[0],train_data[1])



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)


X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')



X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')



y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]


def baseline_model():
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

#model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), input_shape=(1, 10, 10), activation='relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name = 'first_dense_layer'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model



# build the model
model = baseline_model()
# Fit the model
hist=model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=30, batch_size=100, verbose=2)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))



score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test Loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

test_image = X_test[0:1]
print (test_image.shape)

print(model.predict(test_image))
print(model.predict_classes(test_image))
print(y_test[0:1])




# define the larger model
def larger_model():
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(30, (5, 5), input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', name='first_dense_layer'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model


# build the model
model = larger_model()
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=200)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Large CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

I am trying to resize my model using opencv, it is generating the following error:
**/root/mc-x64-2.7/conda-bld/opencv-3_1482254119970/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3229: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function resize**

Comment: It would be better if you posted your code and sample of the data

Comment: There is separate group for data science and machine learning which will be useful for u

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You recently edited your post and included *another* question. Please ask just one question at a time, and consider asking about that error you get in another post.

Comment: I was told to wait for 6 days before asking any other question. As it was urgent so I post it here.

Answer (score 0):

> How to improve the accuracy?

A bit hard to give a detailed answer from what you posted, and without seeing some data sample, but still will attempt a stab at this. What I can see that may help improve you accuracy is:

1. **Get more data**. In Deep Learning one usually works with big amount of data, and models almost always improve when adding more data. If you can't obtain new data you may try to *generate more samples with the ones you got*, by adding noise or similar modifications.
2. I see you currently have 30 and 10 epochs on the training of your model. **I suggest you increase the number of epochs**, so your model has more time to converge. This also most of the times improves performance up to a point.
3. I also see that your batch size is 100 and 200 on your models. **You can try reducing the batch size of your training process**, so your training performs gradient update more times on each epoch (remember that you can even use `batch_size=1` to upgrade your model for *each* sample, instead of batches).
4. Alternatively, you can try **iteratively increasing the complexity and layers of your architecture and compare your performances**. It is best to **start with a simple model**, train and test, and then add layers and nodes until you are satisfied with the results. I also see you have tried a hybrid convolutional and non-convolutional approach; you can well try starting with just one of the approaches before increasing the complexity of your architecture.